# Lipschitz continuity, product function

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

I have the next function and I'm trying to see if it's Lipschitz continous or not:

Let $(V,|| \cdot||)$ be a normed space
$$\mathbb{R} \times V\rightarrow V,(\lambda,v) \mapsto \lambda v$$

This is what I've tried:

Let $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}, v,w \in V$

$d_{\mathbb{R}\times V}((\lambda,v),(\lambda,w)) = d_{\mathbb{R}}(\lambda,\lambda) + d_V(v,w) = |\lambda - \lambda| ||v-w||_v = ||v-w||_v$

On the other hand,

$d_v(\cdot(\lambda,v),\cdot(\lambda,w))=||\lambda v - \lambda w||_v = ||\lambda(v-w)||_v = |\lambda|||v-w||_v$

To see that is Lipschitz continous we want: $$d_v(\cdot(\lambda,v),\cdot(\lambda,w)) \leq c d_{\mathbb{R}\times V}((\lambda,v),(\lambda,w))$$

But this is where I got stuck, I don't know how to prove if the inequality follows or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not Lipschitz  even in one-dimension.  Assuming that you are using the 'sum-norm' on the product space, Lipschitz condition says $\|\lambda v-\lambda' v' \| \leq C [|\lambda -\lambda'|+\|v-v'\|]$. If $V$ is the real line this gives $|\lambda^{2} -\lambda'^{2}|\leq 2C |\lambda -\lambda'|$ when $v=\lambda $ and $v'=\lambda'$. It is obvious that this inequality is not true. [Of course, the result is same irrespective of what norm you use on the product $\mathbb R \times \mathbb R $].

Comment: What do you mean by "If V is the real line"

Comment: If the result it true for any normed space $V$ it must be true when $V=\mathbb R$ with $\|x\|=|x|$. I have shown that the function is not Lipschitz in this special case, so it cannot be true in general.  @AlejandroZuñiga